# Capture the last timestamp, without reading the complete file using Python

Tags: python, regex, timestamp, analytics

I am fairly new to python and I trying to capture the last line on a syslog file using python but unable to do so. This is a huge log file so I want to avoid loading the complete file in memory. I just want to read the last line of the file and capture the timestamp for further analysis.

I have the below code which captures all the timestamps into a python dict which take a really long time to run for it to get to the last timestamp once it completed my plan was to reverse the list and capture the first object in the index[0]:

The lastFile function uses glob module and gives me the most latest log file name which is being fed into recentEdit of the main function.

Is there a better way of doing this

Script1:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import glob
import os
import re

def main():
    syslogDir = (r'Location/*')
    listOfFiles = glob.glob(syslogDir)
    recentEdit  = lastFile(syslogDir)
    print(recentEdit)
    astack=[]
    with open(recentEdit, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            result = [re.findall(r'\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}T\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d+.\d{2}.\d{2}',line)]
            print(result)

def lastFile(i):
    listOfFiles = glob.glob(i)
    latestFile = max(listOfFiles, key=os.path.getctime)
    return(latestFile)



if __name__ == '__main__': main()

Script2:
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
#The readline() gives me the first line of the log file which is also not what I am looking for:



#!/usr/bin/python
import glob
import os
import re

def main():
    syslogDir = (r'Location/*')
    listOfFiles = glob.glob(syslogDir)
    recentEdit  = lastFile(syslogDir)
    print(recentEdit)
    with open(recentEdit, "r") as f:
        fLastLine = f.readline()
        print(fLastLine)
#    astack=[]
#    with open(recentEdit, "r") as f:
#        for line in f:
#            result = [re.findall(r'\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}T\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d+.\d{2}.\d{2}',line)]
#            print(result)

def lastFile(i):
    listOfFiles = glob.glob(i)
    latestFile = max(listOfFiles, key=os.path.getctime)
    return(latestFile)



if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I really appreciate your help!!

Sincerely.

Comment: Does this log file will only have timestamp? nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly go,to the end of the file. Follow these steps:

1.Every time your program runs persist or store the last '\n' index.

2.If you have persisted index of last '\n' then you can directly seek to that index using

```
file.seek(yourpersistedindex)
```

3.after this when you call `file.readline()` you will get the lines starting from yourpersistedindex.

4.Store this index everytime your are running your script.

For Example:
you file **log.txt** has content like:

timestamp1 \n
timestamp2 \n
timestamp3 \n

```
import pickle
lastNewLineIndex = None
#here trying to read the lastNewLineIndex
try:
    rfile = open('pickledfile', 'rb')      
    lastNewLineIndex = pickle.load(rfile)
    rfile.close()
except:
    pass

logfile = open('log.txt','r')
newLastNewLineIndex = None
if lastNewLineIndex:
    #seek(index) will take filepointer to the index
    logfile.seek(lastNewLineIndex)
    #will read the line starting from the index we provided in seek function
    lastLine = logfile.readline()
    print(lastLine)
    #tell() gives you the current index
    newLastNewLineIndex = logfile.tell()
    logfile.close()
else:
    counter = 0
    text = logfile.read()
    for c in text:
        if c == '\n':
            newLastNewLineIndex = counter
        counter+=1


#here saving the new LastNewLineIndex
wfile = open('pickledfile', 'wb')
pickle.dump(newLastNewLineIndex,wfile)
wfile.close()
```

Comment: Hi Azhar, I am not sure I complete understand these steps. As I had mentioned I am fairly new to python. Can you please explain this in more detail, preferably with some sample code example.

Comment: Hi @Rohit I have added this code snippet.Please check it out and if you have any queries drop a comment :)